# Why is the code written in scala 6 times slower than in java?

Tags: java, performance, scala

I am not sure if I make some mistake writing the scala code.
the question is：

```
    The four adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product are 9 × 9 × 8 × 9 = 5832.

    73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934 96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843 85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511 12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557 66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113 62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749 30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866 70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776 65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243 52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397 53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482 83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474 82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881 16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586 17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042 24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408 07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188 84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606 05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725 71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450

    Find the thirteen adjacent digits in the 1000-digit number that have the greatest product. What is the value of this product?
```

the bloger(http://www.ituring.com.cn/article/111574) says the code he written  by `haskell` only takes `6ms`:

```
    import Data.List
    import Data.Char

    main = do
      a <- readFile "008.txt"
      print . maximum . map (product . take 13) . tails $ map digitToInt $ filter isDigit a
```

so I try to use `scala`:

```
    object Main {

      def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
        val begin: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
            val content = Source.fromFile("file/text").filter(_.isDigit).map(_.toInt - '0').toList
            val lists =
              for (i <- 0 to content.size - 13)
                yield content.drop(i).take(13)
            println(lists.maxBy(_.reduce(_ * _)))
        val end: Long = System.currentTimeMillis()
        println(end - begin)
      }
    }
```

But it takes `120ms` averagely.I thought the problem is I/O,but I found it just took `10ms`(I tried to use `FileChannel` instead of `Source`,but it doesn't save much time).It is `map` and `flatmap(for)` operations which takes the most of time.

Then I try to use java to see if the reason is JVM. Unsurprising, java version runs much faster.Just took about `20ms`:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        long begin = System.currentTimeMillis();

        byte[] bytes = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("file/text"));
        List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
        for(int i=0;i<bytes.length;i++){
            if(bytes[i]-'0'>=0&&bytes[i]-'0'<=9) list.add(bytes[i]-'0');
        }

        int max=-1;
        List<Integer> maxList=new ArrayList<>();
        List<Integer> temp=new ArrayList<>();

        for(int i=0;i<=list.size()-13;i++){
            int value=1;
            for(int j=i;j<i+13;j++){
                temp.add(list.get(j));
                value*=list.get(j);
            }
            if(value > max) {
                max = value;
                maxList.clear();
                maxList.addAll(temp);
            }
            temp.clear();
        }
        System.out.println(maxList);
        long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
        System.out.println(end - begin);
    }
```

My question is why the code of scala version runs so slowly?

Comment: This isn't surprising, nor unusual. The iterative method used in the Java code is naturally much faster. The times are still pretty small to be certain. There are, of course, ways to speed up the Scala version, but Scala is notorious for being slower than Java

Comment: The `drop(i)` takes what should be an O(n) algorithm and makes it O(n^2). This is why your Scala solution isn't scaling. Also, there is no need for the `toList`, just invoke `sliding` as Kigyo suggests on the `Iterator` itself.

Comment: Note that foreach (and it's analogous, contrary to the while loop) [are well know to be problematic from performance POV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6146182/how-to-optimize-for-comprehensions-and-loops-in-scala). There is compiler plugin which eliminate this problem (ScalaCL) and in a long shot scala team will fix it (either with macroses or function handles, both are in research now). See also [Coda Hale's critical response](http://codahale.com/downloads/email-to-donald.txt) it enlists some pitfalls

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As @etherous mentioned: You use mutable state in the Java-version, whereas your Scala-version is completely immutable and also written more inefficiently. They are just different.

You can try to avoid `maxBy` and also try to save already computed results in one iteration. This one should be closer to your Java-version.

```
val content = Source.fromFile("file/text").filter(_.isDigit).map(_.toLong - '0').toList

val result = (0 to content.size - 13).foldLeft((List.empty[Long], -1l)){case (current @(_, curMax), next) => {
    val temp = content.drop(next).take(13)
    val tempVal = temp.reduce(_*_)
    if(tempVal > curMax) (temp, tempVal) else current
  }
}
```

`result` is a tuple here, containing the list of the thirteen numbers as `_1` and it's product as `_2`, as it seems you wanted both.

**Bonus**

Now that I think about it. There is a method called `sliding` that exactly deals with this problem. But I guess it runs as slow as your scala-code. At least this would be short :).

```
content.sliding(13).maxBy(_.reduce(_*_))
```

Comment: Thx.It works.About 20ms faster than before in my computer.^_^

Comment: No one mentioned that the int-valued product overflows. It must be long.

Comment: @som-snytt true! changed to `Long`.

Answer (score 4):

The scala version runs slowly because you're passing around a bunch of functions and creating a lot of intermediate objects. The haskell version is fast because it's built around these idioms instead of scala which is hacked into the JVM. You can get equivilant performance in scala if you write it as you would java (20ms for me, same as your java):

```
  import scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer

  val begin = System.currentTimeMillis()

  val buf = new ArrayBuffer[Int]()

  val test = "73167176531330624919225119674426574742355349194934 96983520312774506326239578318016984801869478851843 85861560789112949495459501737958331952853208805511 12540698747158523863050715693290963295227443043557 66896648950445244523161731856403098711121722383113 62229893423380308135336276614282806444486645238749 30358907296290491560440772390713810515859307960866 70172427121883998797908792274921901699720888093776 65727333001053367881220235421809751254540594752243 52584907711670556013604839586446706324415722155397 53697817977846174064955149290862569321978468622482 83972241375657056057490261407972968652414535100474 82166370484403199890008895243450658541227588666881 16427171479924442928230863465674813919123162824586 17866458359124566529476545682848912883142607690042 24219022671055626321111109370544217506941658960408 07198403850962455444362981230987879927244284909188 84580156166097919133875499200524063689912560717606 05886116467109405077541002256983155200055935729725 71636269561882670428252483600823257530420752963450"

  val d = test.toCharArray

  var i = 0
  while (i != d.length) {
    val c = d(i) - '0'
    if (c >= 0 && c <= 9) {
      buf += c
    }
    i += 1
  }


  i = 0
  var max = 0
  var maxStart = 0
  while (i != buf.length - 13) {
   val test = buf(i) * buf(i + 1) * buf(i + 2) * buf(i + 3) * buf(i +4) * buf(i + 5) * buf(i + 6) * buf(i + 7) * buf(i + 8)* buf(i + 9)* buf(i + 10)* buf(i + 11)* buf(i + 12)
   if (test > max){
      max = test
      maxStart = i
    }
    i += 1
  }


  System.out.println(buf.slice(maxStart, maxStart + 13))
  val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
  println(end - begin)
```

Which prints out:

```
ArrayBuffer(9, 7, 8, 1, 7, 9, 7, 7, 8, 4, 6, 1, 7)
20
```

**UPDATE**

It looks like the JVM can optimize this quite a bit and this goes down to 1ms for me after 50 iterations:

```
object Main extends App {

  (1 until 50).foreach(i => {
    val begin = System.currentTimeMillis()

    val max = Source.fromFile("file/text")
      .toList
      .filter(_.isDigit)
      .map(_.toInt - '0')
      .sliding(13)
      .maxBy(_.reduce(_ * _))

    println(max)
    val end = System.currentTimeMillis()
    println(end - begin)
  })

}
```

Prints:

```
List(9, 7, 8, 1, 7, 9, 7, 7, 8, 4, 6, 1, 7)
144
...
List(9, 7, 8, 1, 7, 9, 7, 7, 8, 4, 6, 1, 7)
1
```

Comment: The fun ends here :(. +1

Comment: @Kigyo it's still better than the java version :)

Comment: @Kigyo looks like scala might be okay after all

Answer (score 1):

One more variant, just for the fun of it. It does not transform String to the List of Longs in one go. 18 ms in console.

```
def findMax(startTime:Long, maxStretch:List[Long], currentStretch:List[Long], longLine:String, currentProd:Long):(List[Long], Long, Long) = 
     longLine match {
     case "" => (maxStretch, maxStretch.product, System.currentTimeMillis - startTime)
     case _ => {
     val nextElement = longLine(0)
     val lastElement = currentStretch(0)
     val nextStretch = currentStretch.tail ++ List(nextElement.toLong-'0'.toLong)
     val nextProd = nextStretch.product
     val (nextMaxStretch, nextMaxProd) = if(nextProd>currentProd) {(nextStretch, nextProd)} else (maxStretch, currentProd)
     findMax(startTime,nextMaxStretch, nextStretch, longLine.substring(1),nextMaxProd)
     }
}

val strContent = <long string>.replaceAll(" ","")
val start = strContent.take(13).map(_.toLong-'0'.toLong).toList

scala> findMax(System.currentTimeMillis, start, start, strContent.drop(13), start.product)
res47: (List[Long], Long, Long) = (List(5, 5, 7, 6, 6, 8, 9, 6, 6, 4, 8, 9, 5),23514624000,18)
```