# Distributing the work over multiple actors?

Tags: scala, akka, actor, distributed-system

I have written a program in Scala, that generates an array of n random numbers ( where n is a large value) and then computes the average of those numbers, as follows,

```
 object HelloWorld {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    val myarray = Array.ofDim[Int](1000000)
    var sum = 0
    for (i <- 0 until 1000000) {
      myarray(i) = (Math.random() * 1000000).toInt
      println(myarray(i))
      sum = sum + myarray(i) 
    }
      println("average " + sum/1000)
  }
}
```

but now i want to do the above computations, by distributing the work over multiple actors, each of which computes the sum of a subrange of the values, sending the result to an actor that combines the result.

I am fairly new to the Actor Model concept, so I need some help on how to start on this ?

Comment: If your intention is to solve some problem and not to learn actor model, you should check out [spark](http://spark.apache.org/), it has all features you mentioned.

Comment: Are you trying to solve the problem similar to this one? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23965737/why-is-the-code-written-in-scala-6-times-slower-than-in-java/25620390#25620390

Comment: I assume this is an assignment. What have you considered so far? Is it the use of actors at all? How to divide up the work across actors? Or something else?